# Viewpager not clearing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having this problem with nested viewpagers.

I have two levels of viewpager. Lets call it levelOneViewPager inside which I have one more viewpager, let's call this levelTwoViewPager.

The Activity loads the data for levelOneViewPager and sets the adapter.

The levelOneViewPager loads data for levelTwoViewPager in onViewCreated and sets the adapter.

Everything works fine when the levelOneViewPager loads data for first time.

Now here is the problem.
First page of levelOneViewPager is loaded, I move to 4th page and come back to first page and the app crashes.
Reason, now first page of levelOneViewPager is recreated and is loading the data, even before it sets adapter, the fragments of levelTwoViewPager are created and is accessing some data in the parent fragment which is not available yet.

How is this happening? I haven't set the adapter to levelTwoViewPager yet but fragments are created for it.

(I tried using both FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter, it's the same behaviour)

Answer (score -1):

add offscreenpage limit to parent viewpager this should fix the issue

Comment: How will that fix the issue? It doesn't make sense. Anyway, I tried, it's still the same.

Comment: if you ser limit to zero it will recreate parent fragment each time which means child fragment will be also created again

Comment: You can't set offscreenpagelimit to 0,  by default it is always 1. Anything below 1 you try to set it discards.